# Where did the Whovian Times' history of Morbius come from?

Tags: doctor-who

In the later days of the old *Doctor Who* series, the show became fairly popular in America.  It was shown on many public television stations in the 1980s.  (For a while, I remember KOAP television in Portland, Oregon showed an episode every weekday.)

There was a regular *Who* convention circuit in America during this period.  The events were mostly put on by the Doctor Who Fan Club of America, which also published a newsletter called the *[Whovian Times](https://archive.org/search.php?query=whovian%20times)*.  In the [double issue 12-13](https://archive.org/details/WhovianTimesV12-13) (at one convention, I remember the DWFCA president joking that they had a quarterly newsletter than only came out three times a year), there was a page-long story about the background of the supposedly most wicked of all renegade Time Lords, Morbius.*  This story (from page 11) is bylined as being written by Tom Beck, but I was wondering where he got the information.  Was it just made up out of Beck's head, or was there some more official source.

*The *Whovian Times* also published retrospectives about major enemies, such as the Cybermen, but these were generally just drawn from the stories in which they appeared.  Morbius was limited to a single appearance in the show, and most of the story clearly originated elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's safe to surmise that it was all fanfic.

[The Tardis Wiki page for Morbius](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Morbius) covers all appearances of the character from all the novels, Big Finish adventures, and other sources accepted as canon, or at least canon until the TV show says otherwise. At the time the article was written, I don't believe any of said new adventures had been written.